# Mac Terminal keyboard shortcuts for Page Up/Page Down

Tags: mac, keyboard, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

I had a mac-newbie friend ask me about scrolling to the top and bottom of the window in Terminal.  Also, paging up and paging down.  I gave him a satisfactory answer (basically hold down the fn key and use he up/down, left/right arrow keys), but he pointed out something I never bothered with before:

If you look under the View menu, there are keyboard shortcuts for these actions.  The ones for page up and page down show a key combination of command plus some other keystroke (see the screen grab below, I don't have the rep to insert a picture directly into the post)

[image]

WHAT on earth are those funny up and down arrows with the perpendicular lines through them?  What keys do they represent?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

⇞ and ⇟ are symbols for page up and page down. ⌘⇞ and ⌘⇟ seem to be identical to ⇞ and ⇟ though.

If others search for how to scroll a page up or down in processes like less or emacs, you can use ⇧⇞ (shift-page up) or ⇧⇟ (shift-page down).

Comment: Interesting -- I'd never seen those symbols before, they aren't on my MBP keyboard.  Thanks.

Comment: On the MBP, Fn+Up is page up and Fn+Down is page down in the terminal, Fn+Left and Fn+Right are Home and End.

Comment: "seem to be identical": They behave identically with and without the Command modifier key normally. The scrolling menu commands and shortcuts are there so that you can invoke them when Home, End, Page Up or Page Down are mapped to something else (in **Terminal > Preferences > Profiles > [profile] > Keyboard**).

Answer (score 5):

On Macbook Pro, `fn+up` and `fn+down` are Page Up and Page Down, respectively.